# Program returning blinking Cursor

Tags: bubble-sort, bluej, compareto

So im doing a sort Method using the bubble sort and compareTo method

Yet for some reason, when I run the program it compiles, does no errors whatsoever and shows a blinking cursor in the program (as if u are about to type something in; which u can, just when u press enter nothing happens) and this cursor keeps blinking.

What's wrong here ? (code based on teacher's instructions)

```
public static void sort(ArrayList al)
 {     
   Person p,p1,p2;
   String a1,a2;

   boolean flag = true;

   System.out.println("Database will be sorted acc to ID ");
   System.out.println();

    do
    {
        flag = false;

        for (int i=0;i<al.size()-1;i++)    
        {
            p = (Person)al.get(i);

             a1=((Person)al.get(i)).personID;
             a2=((Person)al.get(i+1)).personID;

            if (a1.compareTo(a2) > 0){
                p1= (Person)al.get(i);
                p2 =(Person)al.get(i+1);                
        }
    } 
  } 
    while (flag = true);
```

---

```
if (flag = false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
   {
       p = (Person) al.get(i);

       System.out.println("----------" + (i+1) + "-----------");

       System.out.println("ID Number: "+ p.personID);
       System.out.println("Name: "+ p.name);
       System.out.println("Day of Birth: " +p.dayDOB);
       System.out.println("Month of Birth: " +p.monthDOB);
       System.out.println("Year of Birth: " +p.yearDOB);
       System.out.println("Telephone Number: " +p.telNum);
       System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this loop:

```
do
{
....
} 
while (flag = true);
```

You want to compare `flag` to `true`, i.e. `flag == true`, but instead you *set* `flag` to `true` with `flag = true`.  Therefore, the loop will not exit, but instead run forever (or until you terminate the program).

You have the same problem in the following `if` statement.